# Compactness and the Limit

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, compactness, closed-form

Prove that the set

$Y=\{0\} \cup\left\{\frac{\cos k}{k^{3}} \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is a compact subset of $R$.

From the definition of compactness, it is sufficient to show the closedness and boundedness of the given set $Y$. Using the fact that the $cos$ function is bounded above for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we can easily deduce the boundedness of $Y$ (and if not mistaken, using the squeeze theorem implies the limit of $\frac{cos k}{k^{3}}$ is zero). However, in order to show the closedness, it will be enough to prove all boundary points of $Y$ are in the set itself - intuitively, there seems to be only one boundary point - $\{0\}$, but I can not prove mathematically why this is the case.

Comment: This is just a minor thing, but it's making me itchy: you should exclude $k=0$ in your definition because the denominator is $0$.

Comment: Well, depending on the geolocation, the set $N$ mostly refers to the set of positive integers in most countries. Specifically, it has been addressed as "natural integers" in this case; however, thanks for pointing out this for the future problems in order to reduce ambiguity

Comment: Now that's curious. Where are you from?

Comment: Azerbaijan, one of the post-soviet countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us prove  a general fact: Let $(x_n)$ be  sequence in a $\mathbb  R$ which converges to a point $a=x$. Then $A=\{x\} \cup \{x_1,x_2,...\}$ is compact.

Proof: Let $(U_n)$ be an open cover of $A$. Then $x \in U_k$ for some $k$. Since $x_n \to x$ we have $x_n \in U_k$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, say for all $n \geq m$. Pick $k_1,k_2,...,k_{m-1}$ such that $x_i \in U_{k_i}$ for $ 1 \leq i <m$. Then $U_k$ together with $U_{k_i}: 1 \leq i <m$ gives a finite subcover.

Alternatively, you can show that the only limit point of $A$ is $x$, so $A$ contains all its limit points, making $A$ closed and bounded.

Comment: First of all, thank you for providing such a comprehensive general property about compact sets and sequences. What I became more curious about is how mathematically, we can show the sequence $x_{k} = \frac{cos k}{k^3}$ is indeed having limit zero, not its absolute value (otherwise, it would fairly simple application of squeeze). Moreover, what exact approaches would you make to conclude that the only limit point of $A$ is $x$ - it seems obvious from the intuitive perspective, but I always wished to see more formal proof of this easy lemma.

Comment: Just from looking at the fact that the cosine is bounded and $1/k^3\longrightarrow 0$ it is quite clear that $x_k\longrightarrow 0$. If you wanted to be super formal you'd have to show that for aribtrary small $\epsilon$ it holds $|\cos(k)/k^3|\le\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $k$, which is true say for $k>\epsilon^{-1/3}$.

Comment: As for why 0 is the only limit point, honestly I don't have a formal argument off the top of my head. It just seems obvious if you try to imagine the sequence. I'm sure you could come up with one easily enough though. In fact, i'm pretty sure all points but 0 are isolated points.

Answer (score 0):

Your set is actually completely made of boundary points: every neighborhood of each point contains points which are not in $Y$. Your intuition rightfully suggested you the origin is a special point in the set but it's not the only boundary point, rather it's the only *accumulation point*: every neighborhood of the origin contains points of $Y$ other than $0$.

Comment: How can you show that each element of the RHS set has a small neighbourhood containing points both from the set $Y$ and its complement? I do not believe it is mathematically feasible to prove it.

Comment: @AnarRzayev it’s a general fact for convergent sequences. A second limit point would imply a convergent subsequence converging to it, contradicting unicity of limits.

Comment: @AnarRzayev on the contrary, it is quite evident. Here's one way to see it: fix a $k_0\neq0$, then since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ there is a rational $x$ arbitrarily close to $\cos(k_0)/k_0$. Since $x$ is rational it is of the form $x=p/q$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime integers, from which you can easily conlcude that $x$ is not in $Y$.

Comment: I meant $\cos(k_0)/k_0^3$, sorry.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Precisely, that is indeed what I had mentioned in the current post. The elements of the RHS set have $0$ as the only limit point.